# Android Button Assets

Tags: android, android-layout

When developing for Android, a common problem I face involves button assets.

Problem: A UI Designer will want a particular button look and feel (typically just a different color than a standard Android Holo Button).

How should I accomplish this? I just don't know the right way to go about it...

Should I

a) Create the button with a HEX color code and have a shape/ selectors

b) Have the UI designer drop me drawables for the button and drawables for the selected state?

Answer (score 2):

If you can style the buttons using native drawables (shapes, gradients, rounded borders, etc) then go for that, else you will need to use a 9-patch drawable.

Answer (score 1):

In drawable folder create an xml file named custom_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/actionButtonColor2"
                android:endColor="@color/actionButtonColor1"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/activeBorder" />
            <corners
                android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/actionButtonColor1"
                android:endColor="@color/actionButtonColor2"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/highlightBorder" />
            <corners
                android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/disabledStartColor"
                android:endColor="@color/disabledEndColor"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/inactiveBorder" />
            <corners
                android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/actionButtonColor1"
                android:endColor="@color/actionButtonColor2"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/activeBorder" />
            <corners
                android:radius="5dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:left="10dp"
                android:right="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Then, in the activity

```
 <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/up"
                    android:id="@+id/buttonUp1"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button2"/>
```